# How to set up server to install iphone app from url (for development)

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I put my .ipa file on http://www.diawi.com/ and can serve it and install it fine.

However, I am trying to set this up on my server and it does not want to work.

My URL ends with .ipa as per diawi URLs.

I am serving it with the following headers:

```
Cache-Control:public
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Speaking Email.ipa"
Content-Length:644878
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Fri, 20 Mar 2015 06:54:00 GMT
Expires:Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 20 Mar 2015 06:43:39 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

The headers on diawi.com are:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Speaking Email.ipa"
Content-Length:644878
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Fri, 20 Mar 2015 07:09:22 GMT
ETag:"550bc49e-9d70e"
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 20 Mar 2015 06:56:30 GMT
Server:nginx
Set-Cookie:__utmmobile=0x4bf390e7f5e82765; expires=Sun, 19-Mar-2017 07:09:22 GMT; Max-Age=63072000; path=/
Set-Cookie:insc=2; expires=Fri, 20-Mar-2015 07:10:22 GMT; Max-Age=60
```

When I download the two IPAs and rename them to ZIP and Beyond Compare them, they are identical. So they are not doing anything special with the IPA or the headers as far as I can tell...

How do they do it? (Also PhoneGap build does this same thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to link the .ipa, you have to link a .plist

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://www.yourserver.com/yourApp/manifest.plist">Install the App</a>
```

And the manifest.plist should be something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
            <key>items</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>assets</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>kind</key>
                            <string>software-package</string>
                            <key>url</key>
                            <string>http://www.yourserver.com/yourApp/YourAppName.ipa</string>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                    <key>metadata</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                        <string>com.yourcompany.YourAppName</string>
                        <key>kind</key>
                        <string>software</string>
                        <key>title</key>
                        <string>iOS Test App</string>
                    </dict>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: Thanks. That is not what diawi does - they link to the .ipa - but I will try this suggestion thanks.

Comment: Yes that works! I had to include a HTTPS link though rather than HTTP. and add plist as a valid mime type (application/octet-stream) to server.

Comment: @mikenelson How to set mime type to ftp server. I am facing issue while downloading app. Manifest files shows as a raw string in browser rather downloading. Please Help me with this.

Comment: @Rajesh, you need a HTTPS server and configure it for the server. How to do it depends on the server you use.